# Could not load file or assembly 'Extensions' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net

I extended a few controls and placed them in "Extensions" folder under my Application root. However I'm getting this error :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Extensions' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Line 7:  <%@ Register TagPrefix="RE" Namespace="MyApplication.Extensions" Assembly="Extensions" %>
Line 8:
```

I tried the following :

1- Deleting the contents of Temporary ASP.Net files
2- Cleaning- Rebuilding
3- Closing and opening visual studio 2012 but still i get the same error

Any other suggestions why it could possibly not be able to see the Extensions folder ?

Comment: _"Extensions folder under My Application root"_ but `Assembly="Extensions"`? Isn't assembly the one of your application?

Comment: Can you please point out the problem ? I'm new to extending controls and was following a sample tutorial.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I'm not sure what you mean, can you help me with the correct syntax ?

Comment: @user3340627 : What is Extensions ? is it your class ?

Comment: Extensions is the folder that contains the classes for extended controls

Answer (score 1):

From Adriano Repetti's comment above, it turned out I was using the wrong Assembly, so here's the correct way to register :

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="RE" Namespace="MyApplication.Extensions" Assembly="MyApplication" %>
```

Comment: Yes, you can also simply drop it (it's optional, not required).

Comment: I tried dropping it but i got "Unknown server Tag" for my extended controls, I guess it's something in my solution